# MySQL - Select specific tables from database

Tags: mysql, database

I need to get some specific tables in the database, sample.

```
SELECT table1, table2 table3 FROM data_base ORDER BY DESC;
```

I have found that I can do to get all tables: SHOW TABLES; But I want to bring me specific tables.

¿They know any way?

**I found this way also:**

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS tb_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'city' AND TABLE_NAME = 'city'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test_offers';
```

But it shows one specific table if another conditional, then shows me many repeated tables.

Much appreciate your support!

Comment: what's the purpose behind this?

Comment: you can put table names like `table_name in ('city','table1','table2')` to get multiple tables

Comment: I want to add from an administration panel, a menu list with the option to add multiple records to a table specified in the database, to avoid having to climb a Excel, for example up some specific users, which need to add the ID, name, email etc ...

From an excel I can export an organized structure separated by commas, 123123; Username; 1@1.com by explode PHP I can count the number of columns and an array insert data.

This we will do to multiple tables separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read information from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database. It's columns make for fun perusing.

```
select table_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables  
where table_schema='so_gibberish' 
and table_name in ('jiveturkey','items','casted_by') 
order by table_name;

+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME  |
+-------------+
| casted_by   |
| items       |
| jiveturkey  |
+-------------+
```

Comment: You mean that worked for you too? I knew someone else out there had a `jiveturkey` table ;)

Comment: It works perfectly :), look at several post but showed an example for specific tables, just to get all tables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME in ('city','table1','table2')
AND TABLE_SCHEMA in ('test_offers','tbl1',tbl2');
```

Other wise see this article for more information about this.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: This example works but it brings me a lot of details and characteristics of the tables. Similarly, thank you very much.

Comment: Use table_name instead of *.

Comment: If you can show an example would be perfect and not so experienced user can understand it better. But in the commentary Drew, the example works perfect.